# из с++ в mysql передача данных

Tags: mysql, c++-cli, utf-8, кодировка, cp1251

Есть БД на локалхосте (запускаю через xampp, mysql). В базе присутствует кириллица. Все поля определены как utf8mb4_general_ci.
В приложении с++ (windows form visual studio) получаю данные из БД - все работает. Данные ВЫВОДЯТСЯ корректно. Если пытаюсь через это же приложение изменить данные в базе или добавить новые, то в БД записываются символы ??????????? вместо русских (остальные в порядке).

В проект добавляла MySql.Data в ссылках, далее использую следующий код:

```
String^ constr = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=;Database=travelagency;SSL Mode=None";
         MySqlConnection^ con = gcnew MySqlConnection(constr);
         String^ utf8 = "SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'; SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';";
         String^ sql_set = utf8 + "";
String^ fio = "Васильев Владимир Евгеньевич";
        String^ tel = "89161221111";
        String^ email = "ter@mail.ru";
        String^ adress = "г. Москва, Федоровская ул., д. 15";
        String^ sql_query = sql_set;
        sql_query += "insert into clients (fio, tel, email, adress) values('" + fio + "','" + tel + "','" + email + "','" + adress + "')";
        MySqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand(sql_query, con);

        con->Open();
        MySqlDataReader^ dr = cmd->ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox::Show("Запись добавлена!");
        dr->Close();
        con->Close();
```

Пыталась изменить кодировку и на cp1251, и на 866, не помогает. Изменила кодировку самого файла MyForm.h на UTF8 - не помогло ((( HELP

Comment: Используйте префикс `L` перед строковыми литералами: `L"Васильев"`.

Comment: А также используйте параметры в sql-запросах.

Comment: L на самом деле используется со строками, но одно добавление буквы к значениям не помогло. Нашла MySqlParameter(), но надо разбираться, как ее использовать..

Comment: Это Objective-C ?

Comment: c++/cli создавала в visual studio